# Only update MySQL row if columns equal

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am running this script with PDO:

```
UPDATE orders SET status=:status WHERE id=:id AND depot=:depot;
```

I want it to only update if status = "Open" - so if status is anything but open, I don't want it to update.

How can I do that?

Comment: You know how to test the `id` and `depot` columns, why do you think there's anything different about testing `status`?

Comment: Did you run into a problem including a test on statue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update orders when status is Open

```
UPDATE orders SET status=:status WHERE id=:id AND depot=:depot AND status='Open';
```

If you want to update orders when status is not Open

```
UPDATE orders SET status=:status WHERE id=:id AND depot=:depot AND status!='Open';
```

Hope this works for you!!